# Open WebView like FlipBoard Application

Tags: android, webview

I am using [this Librabry](https://github.com/emilsjolander/android-FlipView) for my project

and my requirement is open WebView and turn page [like This manner](http://www.ahotbrew.com/how-to-implement-flipboard-animation-on-android-tutorial/)

How can i make my webView in this way.. What I did, I added this library in my gradle.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final WebView learn2crack = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
    learn2crack.loadUrl("https://www.google.co.in");
    learn2crack.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
}
```